# For dentro de For (Explicação)

Tags: javascript, for

Voltei a estudar logica, pois estava estudando somente front-end e me bateu uma duvida bem tosca, sobre um for de outro.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <=10  ; i++) {
    for (var i2 = 1; i2 <=10; i2++){
    document.write(i);
    
   }
   }
```

Como vocês viram ele me exibe a variavel i 10 vezes, porém eu só pedi (na logica) que ele me exibisse só primeiro for que seria (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). Porque ele me trouxe os valores do outro for repetidos 10 vezes.
Obs: Façam um explicação bem a fundo, nao consegui entender por pesquisas.

Comment: Como você colocou um for dentro do outro, o primeiro for vai de 1 até 10 e o segundo for também de 1 até 10 e você está pedindo para imprimir o valor da variável do primeiro for dentro do segundo for, isso vai fazer com que o valor do i se repita 10 vezes na primeira interação e assim repetir sucessivamente até acabar. No caso vai imprimir 10 vezes o 1, 10 vezes o 2 ..... até 10 vezes o 10.

Answer (score 4):

Antes de tudo aconselho nunca user `document.write`.

Sobre `For`, ele funciona como uma listagem, se você fizer uma listagem dentro de um item de outra lista essa vai terminar antes.

Através desse exemplo você verá a listagem de cada item por confirmação tornando fácil entender ao ver.
Aconselho testar pelo **Firefox**:

```js
function listar(){
  var lista = document.getElementById("listagem");
  lista.innerHTML = ""; //Limpar listagem para reiniciar
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    lista.innerHTML += "LISTA PAI:" +i + "\n";
    for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
      lista.innerHTML += "\tLista Filho: " +j + "\n";
        alert("Pai "+i+" - Filho: "+j);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="listar()" value="LISTAR" />
<pre id="listagem">
</pre>
```

O `for` *filho* dentro do `for` *pai* tem que terminar sua execução para iniciar o próximo `for` *pai*, ou seja, um pai mandará todos os filhos de cada vez.

Comment: Muito bom!  +1 !

Comment: Uma dúvida: pq vc aconselha testar pelo Firefox?

Comment: Ou IE11, o Chrome ou Opera não mostram alterações na página até todos os  `ALERT` pararem.

Comment: Eu sou mais fã de imprimir no debug. Portanto não gostei do como você exibe a iteração. Mas  a parte explicativa me parece muito boa na primeira olhada

Comment: Se você fosse iniciante poderia nem saber o que é `debug` ou como realmente usar, estou certo?

Answer (score 2):

Ao entrar no segundo `for`, ele irá repetir 10 vezes o `i` do primeiro `for` e assim por diante:

Ao executar o `for i` na primeira vez:

```
irá repetir 10x o valor de `i` no segundo `for` (i2 <=10)
```

Em seguida irá retornar ao `for i` pela segunda vez (agora o `i` é igual a `2`):

```
irá repetir 10x o valor de `i` no segundo `for` novamente
```

E assim sucessivamente até que `i` seja igual a `10`.

O primeiro `for` irá esperar o processamento do segundo `for` para continuar.